# How to generate ObjectFactory classes with methods that use default values?

Tags: java, cxf

I have a WSDL file that use default values and I would like to generate ObjectFactory classes that create methods with those default values using CXF. For example, I have an object defined like this

```
    <xsd:complexType name="Smoker">
            <xsd:sequence>          
                    <xsd:element default="0" minOccurs="0" name="numCigarettesPerDay" nillable="false" type="xsd:integer"/>         
                    <xsd:element default="0" minOccurs="0" name="numYearsSmoking" nillable="false" type="xsd:integer"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
```

And I want to get a method like this

```
    public Smoker createSmoker() {
            Smoker smoker = new Smoker();
            smoker.setNumCigarettesPerDay(0);
            smoker.setNumYearsSmoking(0);
            return smoker;
    }
```

Instead of this one

```
    public Smoker createSmoker() {  
            return new Smoker();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The CXF XJC Default Value Plugin provides and XJC plugin that updates the generated beans to return the default value defined in the schema for fields that are unset in the instance.

There are the links were you can find more information about what you need to do:

- http://cxf.apache.org/cxf-xjc-dv.html
- http://java.net/projects/jaxb2-commons/pages/Default-Value

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've already used that CXF XJC plugin, but this plugin only generates code for each class and not for the `ObjectFactory` class. For example, with the CXF XJC plugin I would get these two methods:

    public Integer getNumCigarettesPerDay() {
        if (numCigarettesPerDay == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        return numCigarettesPerDay;
    }

    public Integer getNumYearsSmoking() {
        if (numYearsSmoking == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        return numYearsSmoking;
    }